# RIP, Ennio Morricone

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Italian composer Ennio Morricone, one of the most prolific writers of motion picture scores, has died at age 91.](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/ennio-morricone-dead-prolific-italian-composer-was-91-858358)  He was perhaps best know for his work on Sergio Leone’s spaghetti westerns, but he wrote a huge number of film scores, in virtually all genres, including science fiction and fantasy.  His work included music for *Nightmare Castle*, *Red Sonja*, *Exorcist II*, and, of course, *The Thing*.

Comment: Morricone was also a direct inspiration for The Plugz song "Reel Ten", from the cult classic, sci fi-ish film *Repo Man*.

Comment: Oh man I literally found out here... RIP... Check out his work for The Hateful Eight... It was another one of his great works, not as well known as his scores for the Westerns but still pretty good.

Comment: https://open.spotify.com/playlist/3vcZOynILyyaG0L56fkWW8?si=qZAbk5r6Q8-NEX5dIvj4Vw Spotify Link

Comment: @AnshumanKumar I think the score for *The Hateful Eight* actually used some material he had written for *The Thing*, but which had never gotten used.  Because of the similarity in setting between the two films, Tarantino liked the idea of using the leftover cues from *The Thing*.

Answer (score 7):

I guess the most humans can hope for is people will see our work in centuries to come -- not one in a million people will be remembered 200 years after their deaths but maybe people will still watch (and listen to) The GB&U.

Comment: Just saw a commercial with [The Ecstasy of Gold](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYI09PMNazw) in it today. I expect it will easily outlast me.You can see it's been in [quite a few places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ecstasy_of_Gold).

Comment: I was amazed that the local Classical music radio station had a special program honoring the work of Morricone. Never thought of him as a classical musician.